# Advanced Search from one textbox

Tags: php, search, advanced-search

I want to implement a advanced search functionality in my program but i don't want to create an interface like this (it's just example):

[image]

What i want is just a text box where user can write queries like this (assume it's a 'contacts' applicaton):

```
contact_name:john,michael,-michelle age:<=20,=>15 location:usa
```

What i thought so far:

First, explode the text by spaces, and then by colon. So, first item will be "search fields" and the second array will be values to look for. But problems come with operators like `<=`, `-` and `*`. They are not fixed width, so i can't know how much character should i do "substr" for operator.

By the way: If this search operation has a general name like "token based search" or something like that, i can search for a library which already does job.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use some regex with [callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Something like :

```
"`[a-z]+:([*<=>])([a-z],)+ `U"
```

It's just an example, you have to complete if to fit your needs.

Good luck with that.

Comment: I already searched Google with everything i can imagine but may be there is a library like Doctrine's Parser or something like it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build something like your advanced search (maybe) using auto-suggest for building user query: this way you will have more control over query structure.
If you attempt to parse freehand queries you leave yourself open to query misinterpretation:

Will you consider below query valid
`contact_name:john,michael,-michelle age:<=20,=>15 location:usa`
and the following representation of the same invalid?
`contact_name:john, michael,-michelle age:<=20,=>15 location:usa`
(insert any number of spaces just about anywhere)

Try to search for "query builders" or something similar, but considering that the implementation is **very** application specific I am not sure if you will find anything useful.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer. I think i can "trim" the space before "michael" if a Query Builder gives me " michael". I will do some more Google research. Thanks :)